# Password changed for no reason?

Tags: 12.04, login, password, encryption, password-recovery

I'm having a problem logging into my computer. I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I am 100% sure I didn't change my password, although I tried typing it 100 times, it's not working.

I restarted the computer, I made sure I didn't have caps on or that the layout didn't change, I even tried logging in with ssh, but the password seems to have been changed. I am the only one using my computer. I have a ssd drive and I've heard others complaining to have the same issue with such drives.

I chose to encrypt the home folder when I installed Ubuntu, and I'd like to get it back. I do understand that the whole point of an encrypted home is to be unable to decrypt it, but since I didn't change the password, maybe there's a way ? Maybe, for example, the logging password changed, but not the password that encrypts the home folder ?

What can I do to be able to login again, or at least to get my stuff back?

edit: although I still don't understand why I can't login, I tried using a live CD, and ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase seems to work when I input the right password, which probably means that all is not lost. I really need help for step by step instructions to decrypt my home file, having the correct password. I don't want to mess it up, there are important files and I don't want to just go and try things I find on google.

Answer (score 0):

To change the password of a given user, just use the `passwd` command. For example, if I wanted to change the password of **admin**, I would use this command:

```
sudo passwd admin
```

This would be used to reset your password.

I hope I helped :)